# Update to Kotlin 1.3.30 breaks build with Dagger 2.21

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, dagger

Build error after update from Kotling 1.3.21 to 1.3.30:

```
AppComponent.java:16: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding]    
   java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<? extends androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>,
   javax.inject.Provider<androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>> 
   cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
```

Reproduced on two different projects with similar dependencies on Kotlin, Dagger and Architecture components.

I suspect it somehow related to the recent kapt updates in kotlin 1.3.30:
https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2019/04/kotlin-1-3-30-released/

Tried to disable/enable the kapt options from the article, tried gradle clean, invalidate caches, nothing helps.
Only downgrading to 1.3.21 projects build successfully.

Comment: It is a humble request to the community to help with a solution to this problem. Maybe someone has already solved this issue.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This bug was already reported by someone [on GitHub](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1478) and [on YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-30979). This should be fixed once Kotlin version 1.3.31 gets released.

**Update:** Kotlin 1.3.31 is out, so make sure to update your Kotlin version!

---

The workaround for Kotlin 1.3.30 listed on GitHub is to use a Java annotation instead of Kotlin for `ViewModelKey`, or you may downgrade back to Kotlin 1.3.21.

```java
/**
 * Workaround in Java due to Dagger/Kotlin not playing well together as of now
 * https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1478
 */
@MapKey
@Documented
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ViewModelKey {
    Class<? extends ViewModel> value();
}
```

Comment: Downgrade your kotlin version to `1.3.21`

Comment: Just use a java class instead... you saved me.

Comment: FYI: 1.3.31 didn't solve it on my side. I still need to use the Java workaround.

Comment: @Forke Interesting. I just gave it a quick try earlier, and it seemed to work for me. Did you do a clean build and cleared the build cache? It may be caching issue or a completely different issue altogether

Comment: I made a mistake installing the new version but leaving the old version configured in the gradle file. Works now. Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 0):

`Upgrade` [dagger version](https://github.com/google/dagger/releases) and [kotlin version](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html) to the `latest`

`annotation class` should work.

Currently the latest version is :-

**Dagger version** :- `2.23.2`

**Kotlin version** :- `1.3.41`