# Dagger injection stopped working after migrating Android Studio and kotlin plugins

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I've written a small app which uses dagger2 for injecting dependencies. Everything was working great (last year), but now, after +6 months, it seems like the app simply stopped working after migrating Android Studio+gradle+kotlin plugin.

After migrating, whenever I try to run the app, I end up with the following error:

```
e: D:\code\work\GESAndroid\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\pt\gov\madeira\newsapp\di\AppComponent.java:8: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<? extends     android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel>,javax.inject.Provider<android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel>> cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
 public abstract interface AppComponent extends dagger.android.AndroidInjector<pt.gov.madeira.newsapp.MyApp> {
                ^
       java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<? extends android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel>,javax.inject.Provider<android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel>> is injected at
           pt.gov.madeira.newsapp.di.viewmodels.ViewModelFactory(viewModels)
       pt.gov.madeira.newsapp.di.viewmodels.ViewModelFactory is injected at
           pt.gov.madeira.newsapp.di.viewmodels.ViewModelModule.bindViewModelFactory$app_debug(factory)
      android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.Factory is injected at
          pt.gov.madeira.newsapp.ui.main.MainActivity.viewModelFactory
       pt.gov.madeira.newsapp.ui.main.MainActivity is injected at
          dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T) [pt.gov.madeira.newsapp.di.AppComponent ? pt.gov.madeira.newsapp.di.ActivityBindingModule_MainActivity$app_debug.MainActivitySubcomponent]
  The following other entry points also depend on it:
      dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T) [pt.gov.madeira.newsapp.di.AppComponent ? pt.gov.madeira.newsapp.di.ActivityBindingModule_ShowDetailsActivity$app_debug.ShowDetailsActivitySubcomponent]
```

Now, can someone please help translate the error? It seems like it's complaining about ViewModel injection, but I'm not sure on why this is happening.

Btw, here's the code I was using to inject the view models:

```
class ViewModelFactory @Inject constructor(
        private val viewModels: @JvmSuppressWildcards  Map<Class<out ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>>
) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T
        = viewModels[modelClass]?.get() as T
}

@Module
abstract class ViewModelModule {
    @Binds
    internal abstract fun bindViewModelFactory(factory: ViewModelFactory): ViewModelProvider.Factory
}
```

And here's the activity binding code:

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityBindingModule {
    @ActivityScoped
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [MainActivityModule::class])
    internal abstract fun mainActivity(): MainActivity

    @ActivityScoped
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [ShowDetailsModule::class])
    internal abstract fun showDetailsActivity(): ShowDetailsActivity
}
```

And here's the activity's injection code:

```
@Module
abstract class ShowDetailsModule {
    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(ShowDetailsViewModel::class)
    abstract fun bindShowDetaislViewModel(viewModel: ShowDetailsViewModel): ViewModel

}

@Module
abstract class MainActivityModule {
    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(MainActivityViewModel::class)
    internal abstract fun bindMainActivityViewModel(viewModel: MainActivityViewModel): ViewModel
}
```

And finally, here's the code for the attributes:

```
@Documented
@Scope
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
annotation class ActivityScoped

@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION, AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_GETTER, AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_SETTER)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@MapKey
annotation class ViewModelKey (val value: KClass<out ViewModel>) {
}
```

So, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Kotlin 1.3.30? Possibly [this issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55647120/1837367)

Comment: Yes, that made the issue go away...now, there are others creeping in :)

Would you mind putting an answer so that I can mark is as correct?